# Managing thread execution in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am currently using worker threads in Python to get tasks from a Queue and execute them, as follows:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def run_job(item)
    #runs an independent job...
    pass    

def workingThread():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        run_job(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
num_worker_threads = 2

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = Thread(target=workingThread)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for item in listOfJobs:
    q.put(item)

q.join()
```

This is functional, but there is an issue: some of the jobs to be executed under the *run_job* function are very memory-demanding and can only be run individually. Given that I could identify these during runtime, how could I manage to put the parallel worker threads to halt their execution until said job is taken care of?

Edit: It has been flagged as a possible duplicate of [Python - Thread that I can pause and resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640283/python-thread-that-i-can-pause-and-resume), and I have referred to this question before asking, and it surely is a reference that has to be cited. However, I don't think it adresses this situation specifically, as it does not consider the jobs being inside a Queue, nor how to specifically point to the other objects that have to be halted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Thread that I can pause and resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640283/python-thread-that-i-can-pause-and-resume)

Answer (score 0):

I would pause/resume the threads so that they run individually.
The following thread
[Python - Thread that I can pause and resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640283/python-thread-that-i-can-pause-and-resume) indicates how to do that.

Comment: This is hardly any help, Jordim. I did my homework before asking here. Please refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering.