# Pause non-iterating process in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

I have a Process, which does not repeat (Selenium Webdriver), which can run up to 100 minutes and more. My problem is that I cant figure out a way to pause in the middle of the process.

I've been trying to resolve it with Events, but so far I just found solutions, which would stop the process **after** an iteration, I've been thinking that it would theoretically be possible to put a query after every line of code, which asks if event is set to continue processing, but that will be very hard, because I have about thousand lines of code in that function.

In this example I have also been trying to pause the main Process over a Event which is called from another process, which starts when the user gives an Input(e.g. Enter), but the processes are not connected and therefor the evet_func is still running further.

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def event_func(num):
    print('\t%r has started' % multiprocessing.current_process())
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(i)
    print('\t%r has finished' % multiprocessing.current_process())

def event_wait(event):
    print("Event Wait called")
    event.wait()
    print("Event wait finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = multiprocessing.Event()

    m = multiprocessing.Process(target=event_func, args=(1,), daemon=True)
    m.start()

    x = input("Waiting for input: ")

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=event_wait, args=(event,))
    p.start()

    print ('main is sleeping')
    time.sleep(2)

    print ('main is setting event')
    event.set()

    m.join()
```

My expected result is that the process is pausable in the middle of the function and not after an iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Using an object of `threading.Event` you can achieve the following resume and pause functionality.

Seems duplicate of :: [Thread that I can pause and resume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640283/thread-that-i-can-pause-and-resume)

Comment: The OP is not using `threading`. The question had the wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.kill` to send `signal.SIGSTOP` and `signal.SIGCONT` to your process to pause it and continue it:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing
import os
import signal

def event_func(num):
    print('\t%r has started' % multiprocessing.current_process())
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(i)
    print('\t%r has finished' % multiprocessing.current_process())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = multiprocessing.Event()
    m = multiprocessing.Process(target=event_func, args=(1,), daemon=True)
    m.start()
    x = input("Waiting for input: ")
    print("Pausing process...")
    os.kill(m.pid, signal.SIGSTOP)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Continuing process")
    os.kill(m.pid, signal.SIGCONT)
    m.join()
```

Comment: If you have to support Windows, you may want to look at [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/). However, it appears to rely on undocumented functions.