# Is there any way to pause and resume thread in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I normally starts the thread using the following command,

`threading.Thread(target=function_name).start()`

Is there any way to pause it like

`threading.Thread(target=name).wait()`

and resume is like

`threading.Thread(target=name).set()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread that I can pause and resume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640283/thread-that-i-can-pause-and-resume)

Comment: I also saw that but unfortunately, I do not think that is the best way when you want to stop for example a function which is processing a large amount of data instead of while looping

Comment: you need to set signals by using a variable, so the thread checks the variable every so on and either stops, waits or starts depending on the value of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

How about check [this](https://pypi.org/project/pythreadworker/) project. This project meets all your requirements. Python's built-in threading module does not support play and pause functionality for now.

So to install that modules: `pip install pythreadworker`

After installation here is a example:

```py
from worker import Worker  # We import the Worker to create thread

def some_long_running_task(foo, bar, tee="foo"):
    do_random_long_stuff()
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # to make a thread we initialise Worker or somewhat so called the Thread of threading module
    thread = Worker(some_long_running_task)  # remember just pass the function without execution parenthesis

    # Now to start thread while also supplying arguments, we call start method
    thread.start("bar", bar="foo", tee=123)

    # To pause a the thread we use pause method
    thread.pause()

    # To resume it we use resume method
    thread.resume()

    # To use the Thread.join Worker class, use the join method
    thread.join()

    # And to kill it we use 
    thread.stop()
```

But do remember while using that if you are using `time.sleep`
then you will have to replace it with `worker.sleep`

so for example you import code is

```py
from time import sleep
```

replace it with

```py
from worker import sleep
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! I gone through the project  but the usage is quite confusing.. for example, If  I want to execute a single function in a thread like this `threading.Thread(target=function_name).start()`, then what will be the scenario in this project ?

Comment: I hope this might help you now

Answer (score 1):

The threading module has a Semaphore, which might help.  If there isn't something already built-in to the threading module, you could try using a Tkinter semaphore variable specific to each thread, and have the thread check its semaphore while in some polling loop.